# Vue filter list by multiple checkboxes

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a data list like this

```
[
   {
      "name":"UMBERTO",
      "description":"Some description",
      "application_area":{
         "LegalCompliance":false,
         "Certification":true,
         "Accounting":true,
         "LifeCycle":true,
         "Reporting":true,
         "DecisionSupport":true,
         "CompanyAssociations":true
      },
      "object_of_observation":{
         "Waste":false,
         "Facilities":false,
         "DangerousSubstances":false,
         "Emission":false,
         "Energy":true,
         "MaterialFlow":true,
      }
   },
   ...
]
```

I want to filter this list by several checkboxes like this:[image]

the filters should be connected by logical AND, right now I have a boolean v-model value for every single checkbox. Is there a more efficient data structure and how can I apply the filters to the data list? I'm using a vuetify data-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object as a dictionary to store the `isActive` state of all your filters;

Your `data()` would look something like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        isFilterActiveMap: {
            "Abfall": false,
            "Gefahrstoffe": false,
            "Energie": false,
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if you need to get the active filters as an array, you can make a computed value:

```
computed: {
    activeFilters() {
        return Object.entries(this.isFilterActiveMap)
                     .filter(([filterType, isActive]) => isActive === true)
                     .map(([filterType]) => filterType);
    }
}
```

But, one [caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) to keep in mind is that you need to update the object using `this.$set` like so:

```
methods: {
    updateFilter(filterType, isActive) {
        this.$set(this.isFilterActiveMap, filterType, isActive);
    }
}
```

With this approach you also don't need to add all your filters to `data()` initially. You could have a `loadFilters` method like so:

```
methods: {
    loadFilters(filters) {
        const isFilterActiveMap = {};
        for (const filter of filters) {
            isFilterActiveMap[filter] = false;
        }
        this.isFilterActiveMap = isFilterActiveMap;
    }
}
```

Then you could have your filters as an array, even outside your component declaration if it doesn't have to be reactive:

```
const filters = ["filter1", "filter2", "filter3"];

export default {
    created() {
        this.loadFilters(filters);
    }
}
```

Or fetch them from an API:

```
export default {
    created() {
        this.fetchFilters().then((filters) => {
            this.loadFilters(filters);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I apply the filter on the data list then?

Comment: using the activeFilters computed, or add some more code so that I can see how you're doing it right now

Comment: thanks, it led me to a solution. The true checkbox values will be added to an array. Then I create arrays from the objects with the boolean attributes and check if every filter array includes the created array